# SUMIF on row in table based on column criteria in different table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table with the following header and totals row:
[image: SegmentValues]
. It has data rows with module names and numbers for the other columns.

I also have this table:
[image: Segments]
. In the `Allocation` column each specific segment gets one of: `CODE_ZONE`, `CONST_ZONE` or `RAM_ZONE`.

For each module (row) in SegmentValues I need to make its `CODE_ZONE`, `CONST_ZONE` or `RAM_ZONE` cell the sum of all the segments allocated there, based on the allocation in Segments. I have tried with this formula: `=SUMIF(Segments[Allocation], "CODE_ZONE", SegmentValues[@[DIFUNCT]:[SECUID]])`, but it only works for the first element. What function should be used in this situation and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `MMULT` function like this:

`=MMULT(SegmentValues[@[DIFUNCT]:[SECUID]],(Segments[Allocation]="CODE_ZONE")+0)`

`MMULT` will multiply each value in a single row with the corresponding values in a single column of the same size (and sum the results for a single value). All values need to be numeric so `(Segments[Allocation]="CODE_ZONE")` returns an array of `TRUE/FALSE` values and adding 0 converts those to `1/0` values

The `SegmentValues` range must not contain blanks, but zeroes are OK

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it using this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SegmentValues[@[DIFUNCT]:[SECUID]]*(SegmentValues[[#Headers],[DIFUNCT]:[SECUID]]=Segments[Segments])*(Segments[Allocation]="CODE_ZONE")
```

It is a SUMPRODUCT with only one array, taken from only one range, but with two conditions:

1. The header of the cell to be added from SegmentValues matches the segment name in Segments.
2. The the cell in the Allocation column corresponding to the said Segment cell is `CODE_ZONE`.

Comment: Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: Yes, I did try it and it generates the exact same results. The only problem is that it imposes two restrictions: adding zero for conversion and SegmentValues not containing blanks.

Comment: Yes "no blanks" is a restriction but +0 is not really a restriction, more like an artefact of the formula. If you want you could also TRANSPOSE one of the arrays in an array formula like `=SUM((Segments[Allocation]="CODE_ZONE")*TRANSPOSE(SegmentValues[@[DIFUNCT]:[SECUID]]))` - needs array entry